# Python Selenium - Cant find elements by Class Name (Specific Site)

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am going crazy with trying to figure out whats going on. I've had zero issues with using this exact process and even can find other classes on this page, but the following two classes come up as empty whenever I run it for this site.

```
browser.get("https://draisgroup.com/las-vegas/beachclub/calendar-view/")
time.sleep(5)
event_name = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'name').text
event_date = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'ddate').text
print("Events Found: " + event_name)
```

Any ideas at all?

I've tried searching by CLASS_NAME and CSS_SELECTOR. This should return a list of event names, and dates in the other variable.

The following code shows 17 items, but none of them display any text.

```
post_elems = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"name")
for p in post_elems:
    print("name: " + p.text)
```

Comment: _the following two classes come up as empty_ What you you mean by "empty"?  You mean it prints `"Events Found: "`  and then  nothing else?  That just means the element didn't have any text, which is perfectly reasonable for certain element types.  You'll have to show us a sample of the actual html.

Comment: @JohnGordon - yes, "Events Found: " returns a blank list. - the url is listed inside of the code: https://draisgroup.com/las-vegas/beachclub/calendar-view/ - on this page - the class "name" and "ddate" are listed for each of the events.

Comment: `find_element()` doesn't return a **list** at all -- it returns **one single element** (presumably the first one it finds).  So I don't know what you mean when you say "returns a blank list".

Comment: I'm going to guess that there is one element near the top of that page with `class="name"`, that has no text.

Comment: not that i can see - i've also tried putting it within a for loop which will show all "names" within its parent div. The parent div shows results, and it iterates through showing event names too, but they're all blank.

`post_elems = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"uv-calev-labels-inner")
print(post_elems)
for post in post_elems:
    event_name = post.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'name').text
    print("Event Name: " + event_name)`
**I cant format this properly lol - stackoverflow noob, but its formatted correctly on my script.

Comment: There are 17 results from searching the parent div, but then looking for the class "name" or class "ddate" there is no text that is visible - but its there if i look at the source code. `<div class='uv-calev-labels-inner'>
<a href='/las-vegas/beachclub/event/EVE110100020230317/'>
<div class='name'>Maria Romano</div>
<div class='ddate'>Fri, Mar 17</div>
</a>`